# PHP Fatal error: APCuIterator::__construct(): APC must be enabled to use APCuIterator

Tags: php, symfony, web

I'm on windows 10 and I work on Symfony 3.4 application.

How can I enable APC to use APCuIteraor?

Actually I get this:

> "PHP Fatal error:  APCuIterator::__construct(): APC must be enabled to
>   use APCuIterator in C:...\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Cache\Traits\ApcuTrait.php (path_of_ApcuTrait.php_in_CACHE)"

when I want to add some new packages in my project with the command `composer require`.

Comment: https://www.phpflow.com/php/how-to-install-apc-cache-on-wamp-and-xampp/ this may be helpful but there is something not right in there, for saying the article is written a couple of months ago as of writing this comment, the php version in the article is 5 so you may need to tweak a couple of thing

Comment: Essentially you need to find the right version of APC to use with your version of php, download the .dll file and put it in your php ext folder and enable it in php.ini

Comment: I downloaded the php_apc.dll file with this url :  https://pecl.php.net/package/APC/3.1.13/windows. Is it the right url ?         
Then i put it in php ext folder.  I also add this line : "zend_extension=apc" in the php.ini file to enable APC but i got the same error. I'm on 64bits OS

Comment: Actually i didn't find the php_apc.dll file for 64bits OS. There are only for 32bits (x84).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Nico Haase. I added these lines in php.ini file :                                              apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_size=32M
apc.ttl=7200
apc.enable_cli=1
apc.serializer=php                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                         
It works !